# display date only from datetime in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, format

I have a jquery date range calendar that has the from and to dates formatted as 
MM/DD/YYYY. I need to take the date from a datetime to compare it in a select statement. I have tried all these options without sucess I am using mysql with PHP

```
if($from != null){
    $whereClause .= " AND date( " . "'" . "m d Y" . "'" . "  , time) BETWEEN " . $from . " AND " . $to .  "";
    //$whereClause .= " AND strftime("%B %e, %Y",time) BETWEEN " . $from . " AND " . $to .  "";
    //$whereClause .= " AND CAST ( time as DATE ) BETWEEN " . $from . " AND " . $to .  "";
    //$whereClause .= " AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), time , 111) ) BETWEEN " . $from . " AND " . $to .  "";
```

Comment: What is your datatype of date filed

Comment: Just make sure that dates are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. How you choose then to display them is up to you.